# how to update uiimage effect when sliding a uislider in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, uislider

I was wondering if it is possible to update a `UIImage` of the `UIImageView` when sliding a slider that increases a float value that is used to make a blur effect in the image? As of now my slider sets a float value and a button makes the blur effect depending on the float value.   Any code would be great.

It looks like this:

```
float hello = [slider value];


    CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setDefaults];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageView.image CGImage]] forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:@(hello) forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];

    CIImage *outputImage = [gaussianBlurFilter outputImage];
    CIContext *context   = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGRect rect          = [outputImage extent];

    // these three lines ensure that the final image is the same size

    rect.origin.x        += (rect.size.width  - imageView.image.size.width ) / 2;
    rect.origin.y        += (rect.size.height - imageView.image.size.height) / 2;
    rect.size            = imageView.image.size;

    CGImageRef cgimg     = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:rect];
    UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    imageView.image =image;
```

Any code would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: hi r u got solution for that .....